# How do magnets work in outer space?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that the earth has two poles that each end of the magnet is attracted to ,but wouldn't that mean that magnets don't work outside of Earth.

Comment: Similar to gravity (though without polarity), an apple is attracted by Earth and so for Earth by apple.  They're action-reaction pair.  The significance is their mass ratios, you hardly observe how Earth is *moved*.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are confusing a compass with a magnet. A compass aligns with earth's magnetic field because its needle is slightly magnetized, but a magnet of the sort that you are thinking of has its own magnetic field. So it would still be attracted to ferromagnetic objects and interact with other magnets in the same way in outer space.

Comment: In principle, compass is a magnetized iron needle and can be regarded as a magnet though it's not permanent in some sense (it can be easily de-magnetized and re-magnetized).